# Error in Connecting to MSSQL Windows Azure Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql-server, database, laravel

I'm working on a project that needs to be connected to a MS SQL Database, I have a cloud database which is hosted in Microsoft Azure, I can access it using SQL Server Management Studio, however in my Laravel project when I tried to query I get . I already allowed my IP Address in the Azure Firewall.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
```

Here's my config

```
'azure' => [
        'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'ybefh1h7kh.database.windows.net,1433'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'prefix'    => '',

    ],
```

My query

```
$users = DB::connection('azure')->select("SELECT * FROM Users");
var_dump($users);exit;
```

Comment: What does the serverlog say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
'azure' => [
    'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'      => 'ybefh1h7kh.database.windows.net,1433',
    'database'  => 'test',
    'username'  => 'myuser',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'prefix'    => '',

],
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I've gone nuts in these past few hours. Thank you so much. Shouldn't have used env.

Comment: if you use this,no need to use env.

Comment: I advice you to use .env files as they are more secure and will make it very easy to migrate to another development/production enviroment.